# Работа с датой в php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, дата

В общем цель такая:
Нужно сделать размещение поста на время (1 год), т е через год пост не должен выводиться.

Сама идея была в том, чтобы в БД создать 2 переменные, 1 - текущая дата, 2 - дата окончания публикации поста и если текущая дата 1 станет больше даты 2, то делаем пост не активированным.

Так вот проблема в том, что не пойму как работать с датами в таблице, что использовать (datetime или timestamp) и какое значение выставлять в самой бд.
Перечитал кучу информации и ничего толком не помогло. Дату окончания публикации поста создаю, а в БД не записывается.

```
$date = time();
$M = idate('m', $date);
$D = idate('d', $date);
$Y = idate('y', $date);
$H = idate('H', $date);
$i = idate('i', $date);
$s = idate('s', $date);
$date_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($H, $i, $s, $M, $D, $Y+1));

echo strtotime($date_end);
$sql = 'UPDATE `agrousadby` SET `mai_date_end` = '.$date_end.' WHERE `id` = '.$Param['id'];
mysqli_query($CONNECT, $sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы просто не хранить время создания поста в базе данных в виде одного значения `DATETIME` (назовем его для определенности `created_at`) и выводить только те записи, которым менее года, отсеивая старые записи при помощи следующего WHERE-условия

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  agrousadby
WHERE
  created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею, сейчас попробую написать

Comment: Сработало. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

> '.$date_end.'
>   Дата в запросе должна быть строкой

```
'. "'" . $date_end. "'" . '
```